# NSMutableDictionary - "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object..."

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have a property in my header file as

`@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary* e;`

and in my viewDidLoad: method allocated it like

`self.e = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];`.

The XCode static analyser is triggered, and says `'Potential leak of an object...'` obviously. But when I release the object (`[self.e release]` in dealloc) the error persists, but now it also is saying that there is an "incorrect decrement of the reference count", and that this object is not owned by the caller (my viewController).

The 'incorrect decrement...' error goes away when I replace `[self.e release]` with simply `[e release]`. But the former error about potential leak is still there. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```
self.e = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

is **over-retaining** the object. Both alloc-init and the property retain the object.

In terms of ownership, you **own** the object returned by alloc-init and by sending it a retain message in the property accessor you claim ownership of it again, which results in the object being over-retained.

You can use a *convenience constructor*, which returns an object **yo do not own**, and let the property accessor claim ownership of it:

```
self.e = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

Or make use of autorelease:

```
self.e = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL] autorelease];
```

Or use a temporary variable:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
self.e = tempDict;
[tempDict release];
```

Comment: Also "[self.e release] in dealloc" is wrong. You should be releasing the private ivar in dealloc. `[e release]` or `[_e release]` depending on how you're synthesizing.

Comment: Of course, @JackLawrence. I did not mention this because the OP wrote: "The `'incorrect decrement...'` error goes away when I replace `[self.e release]` with simply `[e release].`" so I assumed that the `'incorrect decrement...'` error was fixed and only explained the `'Potential leak of an object...'` error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
self.e = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

your property `e` has the retain flag set. Therefore, after it retains it you've increased the retain count by two. You should release the object after handing it over to the property.

```
self.e = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL] autorelease];
```